# Nested dialogs: message being sent twice

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a bot where I am doing something like this:

1) A new Activity (message) arrives.

2) I dispatch the message to a RootDialog.

3) Depending on some Logic, RootDialog can:

```
 a) Call a LuisDialog (handling natural language)

 b) Call a CustomDialog (handles some business logic).
```

But when the user state is reset, and the flow leads to an intention inside the LuisDialog, it calls the intention method twice. Just the first time the state is empty, then it works fine.

Let me show you the code:

**MessagesController:**

```
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            try
            {
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
             ...
            }
     }
```

**RootDialog:**

```
 public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
 {
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await MessageReceivedAsync(context, Awaitable.FromItem(context.Activity.AsMessageActivity()));
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> awaitable)
    {
        bool value = DoSomeCustomLogic();
        if (value) 
        {
            string message = DoSomething();
            await context.PostAsync(message);
        } else {
            bool value2 = DoSomeCustomLogic2();
            if (value2) 
            {
                var answerValidationDialog = new ValidateAnswerWithUserDialog();
                context.Call(answerValidationDialog, ValidateAnswerWithUserDialogCompletedCallback);
            } else {
                var luisDialog = new LuisDialog();
                await context.Forward(luisDialog,LuisDialogCompletedCallback, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
    }
```

Callbacks only do **context.Done(true);**

**And LuisDialog has an Intention which goes like this:**

```
  [LuisIntent(LuisUtils.INTENT_MENU_SALUTE)]
    public async Task SaluteOrMenu(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        if (LuisUtils.IntentScoreIsHighEnough(result))
        {
            string userName = context.Activity.From.Name;
            ContextHelper helper = new ContextHelper(MessageReceived);
            await helper.AskUserToDoSomeInitialAction(context, saluteWord, userName);
            context.Done(true);
        }
        else
        {
            await None(context, result);
        }
    }
```

**And finally class ContextHelper:**

```
public class ContextHelper
{
    private Func<IDialogContext, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>, Task> MessageReceived;

    public ContextHelper(Func<IDialogContext, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>, Task> messageReceived)
    {
        MessageReceived = messageReceived;
    }

    public async Task AskUserToDoSomeInitialAction(IDialogContext context, string saluteWord, string userName)
    {
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();
        List<CardAction> buttons = BuildInitialOptionActions();
        List<CardImage> images = BuildInitialOptionImages();
        string initialText = $"Hi stranger!"
        var card = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = "Hello!"
            Text = initialText,
            Buttons = buttons,
            Images = images
        };
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment> { card.ToAttachment() };
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
        context.Wait(AfterUserChoseOptionInSalute);
    }

    private async Task AfterUserChoseOptionInSalute(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        await ReDispatchMessageReceivedToDialog(context);
    }

    private async Task ReDispatchMessageReceivedToDialog(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await MessageReceived(context, Awaitable.FromItem(context.Activity.AsMessageActivity()));
    }

}
```

The SaluteOrMenu Intention gets called twice (only the first time I interact with the bot or when I delete the state. After Debugging I saw that after doing `context.Wait(AfterUserChoseOptionInSalute);`, the bot calls that function (instead of waiting for an event to call it)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create an small sample where this could be reproduced?

Comment: 0) As I told in the post this happens when bot state is empty (first time a user uses it or when I do /deleteprofile).

1) user types "hi".


2) The logic I said is evaluated (in my  case DoSomeLogic() calls a QnA service and depending on the score it responds back with the question or not). As 'hi' isn't a valid question it forwards the msg to a LuisDialog.


3) Salute Intent gets called and shows a small herocard. it finishes with a context.Wait(AfterUserChoseOptionInSalute);


4) By itself, AfterUserChoseOption gets called, and redispatches the activity (causing another call).

Comment: Yeah I read the post, but unless you want someone to code exactly the same scenario to try to reproduce the issue it will be hard... forwarding/calling dialogs works as expected; so the issue is there in your code.

Comment: Another thing the context.Done(true); in the intent method is executed but also a wait is executed before.So or you wait or you end the dialog; you cannot do  both. the context helper is waiting so you should remove the context.Done<true>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the line that was wrong. It was on the first dialog (the RootDialog):

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
   await MessageReceivedAsync(context, Awaitable.FromItem(context.Activity.AsMessageActivity()));
}
```

That is a line that re dispatches a message with the incoming activity. I had it somewhere in some chunk of code and (don't know why), thought it was a good idea to use it on StartAsync. So, because of that, two calls were occurring.

Dumb me.

I just changed it to this and worked:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```